# Getting subprocess.run(....)'s output written to a file in python3.5 while benchmarking

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, c++14, benchmarking

I am writing a benchmarking driver program in python, whose purpose is to take as input some C++ source-files(.cpp) and then for each input file compile it, make an executable of it(.out) and then run that executable with some input to that executable as command-line argument, and while that executable is running, measure it's time taken(and all) using `/usr/bin/time`.

So, in other words, what this driver program is doing is trying to automate this statement(used to measure timing of an executable):

```
             /usr/bin/time ./way1.out 10 > way1.output
```

In this statment the input to `way1.out`(the C++ program executable) is 10 and the output of C++ program is written to `way1.output`, and then the time taken information is printed to console by `/usr/bin/time`. Ofcourse, in place of 10(as in this statement), it's the driver program job to run this command for all numbers from 1 to 10^6. The driver program will do this for all input C++ source files and for each source file write the output of `/usr/bin/time`(for each value between 1 to 10^6) to another file(which will later be parsed for benchmarking results of that source code).

*This is my driver.py:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import subprocess
import sys

n_limit = 1000000
files_list = ["./src/way1.cpp", "./src/way2.cpp"]

def compile_programs(files_list):
    try:
        for eachFile in files_list:
            subprocess.run(["g++", "-std=c++14", eachFile, "-o", eachFile.split(".")[1].split("/")[2] + ".out"], check=True)
    except:
        print("Some error occured")
        return False

    return True


def benchmark(files_list):

    if compile_programs(files_list):
        print("\n\n Compilation Successful") 
    else:
        raise Exception("Compilation Problem") 

    print("\n\n Benchmarking started..")
    for eachFile in files_list:
        current_file_name = eachFile.split(".")[1].split("/")[2]

        with open(current_file_name + ".results", 'w') as each_file_bench_results:
            for n in range(1, n_limit + 1):

                print(" Currently running for n =", n, " for filename:", eachFile)

                with open(current_file_name+".output", 'w') as current_output_file:
                    completed_process = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/time", "./" + current_file_name + ".out", str(n)], stdout=current_output_file)
                    each_file_bench_results.write(completed_process.stdout)

                subprocess.run(["rm", current_file_name + ".output"])
                print()

    print("\n\n Benchmarking Complete.. Results files are with '.results' extensions")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if (len(sys.argv) == 1):
        print("Using default ./src/way1.cpp and ./src/way2.cpp")
        benchmark(files_list)
    else:
        benchmark(*sys.argv[1:])
```

So, I used python3's `subprocess` module and used it's `run` method i.e. `subprocess.run` on this line :

`completed_process = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/time", "./" + current_file_name                + ".out", str(n)], stdout=current_output_file)`

The C++ program receive the input, they execute, and write their output to a file, **but the output of `/usr/bin/time` is getting printed on terminal**, so I tried this:

`each_file_bench_results.write(completed_process.stdout)`

But, **it turns out that, completed_process.stdout is None** and so will not be written to file, but if I comment this statement out, then the output of `/usr/bin/time` is printed to terminal.

**So, my question is how to get the output of `/usr/bin/time` written to `each_file_bench_results` ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try capturing both STDOUT and STDERR:

```
completed_process = subprocess.run(
    ["/usr/bin/time", "./" + current_file_name + ".out", str(n)],
    stdout=current_output_file, stderr=each_file_bench_results
)
```

It appears that `/usr/bin/time` (at least on my system) writes partially to STDERR. You can also use `subprocess.check_output()` for a bit more convenient approach which gives you a greater control over the received output.

Comment: thanks so much, it worked, but I have a doubt..., why does /usr/bin/time writes to STDERR ?

Comment: Beats me, you'll have to ask its developers - maybe so it can run in the background without interfering with the current STDOUT? Either way, if you check its [source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/OpenBSD/src/usr.bin/time/time.c) you'll see that not partially, but exclusively writes to STDERR.

Comment: Thanks@zwen, I will definitely ask it's developers and have a look at its souce too. Accepting this as answer